# PHP preg_match() - how to exclude words?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP preg_match() to check if some given words are in string.
For example, the string:

```
I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.
```

My regex is built on the fly from a HTML FORM and looks like:

```
/(apple)|(banana)|(work)/i
```

In this example, we have a match, but I would like to **not** match if the string contains "*ways*".
I tried:

```
/(apple)|(banana)|(work)(?<!ways)/i
```

But it also returns 1 (matched)
What should I add to the regex to not match the string example?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use `/^(?!.*\bways\b).*?(?:apple|banana|work)/i`

Comment: Check if the string contains "ways" before. If yes, don't even try your pattern. (remove also the capture groups that are useless).

Comment: Beware of matching words without using word-breaks, because otherwise you may find that `ways` also matches words like `always` or `wayside`.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I'll try the different methods.  anubhava's method seems to be easier to built on the fly.

Comment: Please post your php code so that we can see how you are building on the fly.  Do you need to worry about escaping characters in the `allowed` or `taboo` strings?  I'd like to see how you are building your pattern -- there are some common pitfalls that we can help you with.  And why is ctwheels' pattern too hard to implement?

Answer (score 3):

### Code

I have the two following methods that work for your problem.

#### Method 1

This method uses a capture group to capture the words you want to match.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ppaRIx/1)

```
(?:(?:^(?!.*\bways\b)|\G(?!\A)).*?)\b(apple|banana|work)\b
```

#### Method 2

This method doesn't capture anything, it simply matches. This resets the pattern prior to the word match.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ppaRIx/2)

```
(?:(?:^(?!.*\bways\b)|\G(?!\A)).*?)\K\b(?:apple|banana|work)\b
```

---

### Results

I used two strings to test against. The first contains the word `ways` and the second does not (I removed the `s` so it contains `way` instead).

#### Input

```
I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work. A banana and an apple
I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 way that won't work. A banana and an apple
```

#### Output

Since the output would actually cause more confusion if I just pasted it here, I'll just tell you that it matches `work`, `banana`, and `apple` in the second string and not the first (since the first string contains the negated word `ways`).

---

### Explanation

I'll explain the second method since both methods are very similar, but the second method uses an additional token.

- `(?:(?:^(?!.*\bways\b)|\G(?!\A)).*?)` Match the following

  - `(?:^(?!.*\bways\b)|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

    - `^(?!.*\bways\b)` Match the following

      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
      - `(?!.*\bways\b)` Negative lookahead ensuring the word `ways` does not follow (`\b` is a word boundary assertion so that we don't match words that contain `ways` such as `always` or `wayside` as described in the comments below your question)
    - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\b(?:apple|banana|work)\b` Match any of the words in the group `apple`, `banana`, or `work` literally, while ensuring its word boundaries (so as to not match words containing these words such as `pineapple` or `workplace`)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$your_word = 'way'; // return work
// $your_word = 'ways'; // return null

preg_match('/(ways)/i',"I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 $your_word that won't work.",$x);

if(isset($x[0])=='ways'){ 
    null;
}else{ 
    preg_match('/(apple)|(banana)|(work)/i',"I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.",$z);
    echo $z[0];
}   

?>
```